# Making a Strong HaarCascade Classifier

Tags: c#, emgucv, haar-classifier

I've finally figured out how to make my own classifier and I've managed to make a decent good one working, but the problem now is the accuracy

I have different angles for vehicles that I want to combine into one strong classifier so it'd be able to detect vehicles from front view and side view, the workaround I've concluded is making 2 regions of interest, each using different classifier (one working with front view, other is side view), is this the best workaround for it?

as far as I know the haarcascade classifier extracts features from a selected object and train on that feature.

I also need help with improving my classifiers, is it enough to feed positive/negative photos only to improve it? or I need to change scaling and stuff? and what's the best ratio [+ve/-ve] photos used for training and best stages level

Thanks in advance and sorry for the long post!